# [Java]Trying to create an instance of a class in a jFrame form

Tags: java, user-interface, netbeans

I created an instance of a class in a jFrame Form using NetBeans GUI editor. I create the instance at the top of the class

```
public class AccountCreation_GUI extends javax.swing.JFrame{
Customer n = new Customer(false,false,false,"defult",0.00);//this line
public AccountCreation_GUI() {
    initComponents();
}
```

I get a bunch of exceptions when I run the Program, but without that line of code the program runs. Should I be creating a new instance of the class in every private class? 
I just need a way that multiple private class can see that I have created the instance of the class.

These are the errors I get.

```
run:
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.StackOverflowError
at sun.awt.Win32GraphicsConfig.getBounds(Native Method)
at sun.awt.Win32GraphicsConfig.getBounds(Win32GraphicsConfig.java:222)
at java.awt.Window.init(Window.java:505)
at java.awt.Window.<init>(Window.java:537)
at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:420)
at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:385)
at javax.swing.JFrame.<init>(JFrame.java:189)
at finalprogram.jgoins3.AccountCreation_GUI.<init>    (AccountCreation_GUI.java:19)
at finalprogram.jgoins3.Customer.<init>(Customer.java:13)
at finalprogram.jgoins3.AccountCreation_GUI.<init>
```

Thank in advance.

Comment: Post the error stack you're getting at least... Otherwise it's pretty much impossible to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are trying to do.

```
public class AccountCreation_GUI extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    private Customer n;

    public AccountCreation_GUI() {
     n  = new Customer(false,false,false,"defult",0.00);
    initComponents();
    }
```

Comment: Tried it but got theses the `Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.StackOverflowError
 at sun.awt.Win32GraphicsConfig.getBounds(Native Method)
 at sun.awt.Win32GraphicsConfig.getBounds(Win32GraphicsConfig.java:222)
 at java.awt.Window.init(Window.java:505)
 at java.awt.Window.<init>(Window.java:537)
 at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:420)
 at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:385)
 at javax.swing.JFrame.<init>(JFrame.java:189)
 at finalprogram.jgoins3.AccountCreation_GUI.<init>(AccountCreation_GUI.java:20)`

Comment: What does your Customer constructor look like?

Comment: `public Customer(boolean regular, boolean payAhead, boolean loyal, String userName, double amountOfStorage) {
        this.regular = regular;
        this.payAhead = payAhead;
        this.loyal = loyal;
        this.userName = userName;
        this.amountOfStorage = amountOfStorage;
    }`

Comment: StackOverflowError occurs when you create an infinite loop.  Make sure that is the only place your creating a new customer.  And if it is, try commenting out any other places you create new objects.  That's where I would start.